# How to update MVC 1 application to MVC 3 with razor in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a MVC 1 application who i want to migrate to MVC 3 last days. i make a fresh project and rewrite all logic and put in new.

at a half :- i hear that do not changes in admin. so i include the logic from old code to fresh.

now code is not worked. so all my work look like gone.

Now i thing to migrate the project not by making fresh perhaps by using old solution [proj] i have to make upgraded to MVC 3.

so i can include changes i make in new to old.

so i need a thing that:-

How i can make MVC 1 project to MVC 3 project who can work with razor. second thing i need that used old sollution not making new sollution for migration.

are you know any thing to upgrade i can MVC 1 project to MVC 3 project. How ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Martin Aatmaa has a post on [how to upgrade manually from MVC 1 to MVC 2](http://blog.martin.aatmaa.net/2010/02/09/manually-upgrading-an-asp-net-mvc-1-0-application-to-asp-net-mvc-2-rc2/) or you could try [Eilon Lipton's upgrading tool](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2010/03/10/migrating-asp-net-mvc-1-0-applications-to-asp-net-mvc-2-rtm.aspx)

Then from there you might be able to use [MVC 3 upgrader tool](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/59008) also by [Eilon Lipton](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2010/07/28/migrating-asp-net-mvc-2-applications-to-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1.aspx)

I'm not aware of any tools to upgrade from MVC 1 to MVC 3 directly.

Once upgraded to MVC 3 you will then have to go through each view manually and change the code from an ASPX view to a Razor view.  Note that both view engines can be used along side each other in the same project.

Comment: thanks for help. i like it then someone help me. but as a chance i apply trick already and the work is now done. thanks again.